# Parse URL and function chaining in Rust

Tags: rust

I am just starting with Rust programming.

I'm trying to get the last part of a URL, for example, the URL below I want to get the "**resource**" part:

```
    http://example.com/some_path1/some_path2/resource
```

The code I have now is:

```
    let parsed = Url::parse(url).unwrap();
    let segments = parsed.path_segments().map(|c| c.collect::<Vec<_>>()).unwrap();
    let the_resource = segments.last().unwrap();
```

There must be a more elegant way to do this.

1) How do I write this more elegantly?

2) Is there a way to use only 1 local variable?

Something like:

```
    // This of course does not compile because the returns are a mix of Options and Results
    // But the question is, is there a way to chain the function calls (pipes?)

    let the_resource = Url::parse(url)
                           .path_segments()
                           .map(|c| c.collect::<Vec<_>>())
                           .last()
                           .unwrap();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "elegantly" exactly. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Well, elegance is a subjective matter so I understand now how the question is a bit vague. I meant that explicitly declaring a local variable for each step seems to me a bit too verbose. Just thought maybe there was some syntactic sugar that will let me write just the steps (function calls). Đorđe Zeljić's answer was close to what I was looking for. If there are other ways I'll be happy to learn. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Do you think something like this?

```rust
extern crate url;

fn get_last(url: &str) -> Result<String, &str> {
    url::Url::parse(url)
        .map_err(|_| "Unable to parse")?
        .path_segments()
        .ok_or("No segments")?
        .last()
        .ok_or("No items")
        .map(String::from)
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", get_last("http://zeljic.com/how/to/parse/url/in/rust"));
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6ca92258207b035e6fbe7aee7a4f490b)